# Long term support using git-flow to merge a hotfix to develop branched off the support branch

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow, hotfix

Doing experimental learning of git flow for my new project.. I noticed the following:

The following scenarios:

1. Normally git-flow workings:

   `git flow hotfix start 1.1.2`

   Will create a branch based on master and when done merges with master and develop.
2. Branching based on another branch

   `git flow hotfix start 1.1.3 support/1.x`

   But then the hotfix created based on support branch will merge back into that support branch and not back into develop nor master but will be tagged when finished.

**Problem**

If my master branch is currently in `v3.2.0` but the hotfix was for an issue in a code section introduced in `v1.1` but still relevant and used in the current development branch, how do I go about merging them together?

The reason for this question is that some clients would need long term support of a specific older version even if your newer version is more superior.

**Possibly solution but not( using SourceTree)**

Atlassian SourceTree always only merge finish hotfix with master and develop but never with the support branch that is needed by clients ***(tested thrice)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If my `master` branch is currently in `v3.2.0` but the `hotfix` was for an issue in a code section introduced in `v1.1` but still relevant and used in the current development branch, how do I go about merging them together?

Since you won't merge an `hotfix` branch (where the issue was solved) into master, you can [cherry-pick](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/44444/sourcetree-how-do-i-cherry-pick) the relevant commit back to `master`.

> log view (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>), just select one or more commit lines (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-click or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click multi-selects), then right-click and select '`Cherry pick`'.

[image: https://answers.atlassian.com/download/attachments/15697265/Capture.PNG?version=1&modificationDate=1431431872796&api=v2]

Comment: Thanks it did what I wanted.

Comment: @Sojimaxi Well done. This is appropriate when you know you won't ever merge the source branch to the destination (the one to where you cherry-picked). A merge would duplicate that cherry-picked commit, which isn't good.